# OnItemClickListener to view details of the list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

i have a list of medicine, when user click one of the medicine, it will go to next activity which show the details of the medicine..

below code is the activity with list of medicine.. i know i have to use onclicklistener.. but i dont know how to write

```
public class MedicineView extends Activity 
{
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.medicine_view);
    ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    // view data

    try{
        String query = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_MEDICINE;

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(c!=null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int getIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MED_ID);
            int getNameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MED_NAME);
            int getDosageIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DOSAGE);
            int getFrequencyIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.FREQUENCY);

            if(c.isFirst())
            {
                do{
                    idList.add(c.getLong(getIndex));
                    result.add(c.getString(getNameIndex)+" | " + c.getString(getDosageIndex)
                            +" | " + c.getString(getFrequencyIndex)+"\n" );
                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
        listContent.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        c.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e){  
    }

listContent.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onClickHome(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuUtama.class));
}

public void onClickAdd(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicineAdd.class));
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MedicineDetail.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
} // end class
```

then here is my detailsactivity

```
public class MedicineDetail extends Activity 
 {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Button btnEdit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.medicine_detail);

    int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 2); //i don't know how to do here

    btnEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_MEDICINE + " WHERE id = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

    try{
        if( cursor != null ){
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                   idList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(4));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(5));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(6));
               } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){  
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    TextView StartDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    TextView EndDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    TextView MedName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    TextView Dosage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    TextView Frequency =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TextView Instruction =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView13);

    StartDate.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    EndDate.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    MedName.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    Dosage.setText(cursor.getString(4));
    Frequency.setText(cursor.getString(5));
    Instruction.setText(cursor.getString(6));
    cursor.close();

}

public void onClickHome(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicineView.class));
}

} // end class
```

i dont know what how to do, anyone plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let you class implement the onItemClickListener

`implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

and in `onCreate` add the following line:

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and then overwrite:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    Intent intent = createIntentwithExtra(v, position);
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public Intent createIntentwithExtra(View v, int position)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TaskDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_ID, tasksRepository.get(position).getId());
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: i can go to other activity but how i want to pass the id too @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), MedicineDetail.class);
        startActivity(i);
  
 }

Comment: i check already, it pass the position, but how i want to retrieve the position at another activity

Comment: you could pass the position with the intent. As you can see i am creating an intent in this case using a function createIntentWithExtra and pass there the position and the view, I am adding this function so you could use it, see updated answer.

Comment: just to make sure, why when i write, the tasksrepository is error. what is the function on the taskrepository? and the KEY_ID is the id right? and how to get the id at the next activity?

Comment: TaskRepository is My arraylist of tasks from which i populate the ListView, while the KEY_ID is just a constant string "id" for the key/value pair extra i put into the intent. @user2089567 please open another post if you have more questions. because we are going of the topic of the current question here.

Answer (score 1):

use onItemSelectedListener: arg0 would be the listview and arg2 would be the item position in the adapter

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
}
```